# units of polynomial rings

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

When does a polynomial in the ring of polynomial have an inverse?
 I thought only constant polynomials were units.
if there are other units, under what rings can we guarantee the existence of inverse for non-constant polynomials

Comment: What about non-commutative rings

Answer (score 1):

Well, its an argument involving degrees.

If $f,g$ are polynomials with $f\cdot g=1$, then 
$$0 = {\rm deg}(1) = {\rm deg}(f\cdot g) = {\rm deg}(f) + {\rm deg}(g).$$
The last equality holds if the leading coefficient don't cancel. This holds in integral domains.
Then the degrees of $f$ and $g$ must be zero. Thus $f,g$ are constant polynomials.

Comment: What about rings which are not integral domains

Comment: For polynomial rings over any non integral domain the units in the polynomial ring are precisely the units in the integral domain.